# How did Demikas know the location of the gold room?

Tags: log-horizon

In *Log Horizon*, how did Demikas knew about the location of the room where gold is processed and distributed on the Yamato server?

This happened in *Log Horizon II* episode 11 during the raid, when Demikas pulled Shiroe away from the raid and threw him into the corridor with the door leading to the gold room.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the light novel (Volume 7, Chapter 5, Part 5). I can only guess that he noticed the door somehow or another.

Answer (score 2):

[Demiqas](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Demiqas) was part of the raid party so he was privy to all of the information that was shared throughout the group. It would make sense that all of the members or the raid know the layout of the dungeon. [The Depths of Palm](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Depths%20of%20Palm) was a raid that was done numerous times before but never to the extent of going all the way to the Gold room guarded by the [Kunie Clan](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Kunie).

It is probably safe to say that since Shiroe was able to come to this conclusion by way of research or rumors of the room during the time before the Catastrophe. It is also to note that Shiroe is friends with [ReGan](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/ReGan), and ReGan has a very extensive library at his disposal. ref([Log Horizon Wikia](http://log-horizon.wikia.com))

Comment: Where in the wiki did you source the answer from?

Comment: The problem is that there is not a concrete answer, no where does it reference in the Anime or the Manga where Shiore/Demiqas gained the knowledge of the location of the Gold room. I gave a logical answer based off of character bios and how meticulous Shiroe is.

Comment: I'm wondering how Demiqas knew the "Gold Room" since it is not mentioned where it is located and all they are doing right at that time is fighting against the raid bosses. Even shiroe was shocked when Demiqas pull him away from the fight and take him to that place. This also implies that Shiroe doesn't knew its location.

Comment: Shiroe wasn't shocked that Demiqas knew the location, he was shocked that Demiqas saw that they weren't going to be able to beat the 3 raid bosses so he took it upon himself to get Shiroe to the room which was the entire point of the raid. Shiroe recovers from this initial shock and they both come to the agreement that they hate each other.

Comment: Does it mean that Shiroe knew the location of the Gold room?

Comment: @Victor111 unfortunately we can't know that as a fact it doesn't state in the Anime or Manga whether or not the exact location was known. I based my answer off of the fact that Shiroe was very meticulous and planned everything to the t. So yes he probably either knew exactly where the room was or the general level on which it sat. Demiqas being part of the raid would have been privy to the information of the whereabouts of the room so everyone would be on the same page.

Comment: Great. The question remain unsolved for such reasons. Thank you for the idea, had a great time analyzing that episode.

Answer (score 0):

At ~6:15 into that episode, we're shown part of a map while two of the adventurers recant the plan.  A room is clearly marked as "Goal".

Later on, at ~12 - 12:30, we see a flashback of Shiroe going over the map and the details of the plan.  Presumably, what the adventurers at ~6:15 were recanting was the plan that Shiroe explains during this flashback.

Since all of the adventurers were in attendance, it would make sense that Demikas would know the map.

That doesn't explain why Shiroe didn't know what was going on when he was kidnapped though, which might just be a plot hole to add suspense and give him a reason to doubt Demikas.